# Shadows appear behind subviews when UIViewController.view is clear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, shadow, mmdrawercontroller

I am using [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController).  It is a control that allows center, left and right viewcontrollers.  I want to have one background image showing while all three view controllers have a clear background.  I have that in place, but the problem is that my subviews all have black shadow behind it.  Is there a way to remove all the subviews shadow?

[image: Shadow]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into the MMDrawerController, check out the property `showsShadow`. Try setting it to `NO` when you load the MMDrawerController. It looks like it affects the center view controller. You can also try changing (MMDrawerController.m lines 37/38)

```
CGFloat const MMDrawerDefaultShadowRadius = 10.0f;
CGFloat const MMDrawerDefaultShadowOpacity = 0.8;
```

Comment: That works pre iOS 8.1, too. In Objective-C, `showsShadow = NO` is recommended. However, if you're using Swift, `showsShadow = false` is the way to go.